# Using functions add a list of integers which are separated by comma

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, methods

> Input: 5, 5, 5, 5
>
> Output: 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 20

I am trying to add a list of integers which are separated by comma or hyphen. I have created 3 functions. (Kindly, pardon my variable names for the moment)

1. `delimit` function removes the commas, hyphens, and spaces and stores the result in integerList array.
2. `intConvertedList` function converts the string array elements to an integer type.
3. `sumOfNumbers` function adds the elements in an array.

I am struggling to pass the `delimit` function results to `intConvertedList` and finally, add all the elements from `intConvertedList`. Kindly, show me how the functions will be called in the main method as well.

```
namespace SumOfTwoNum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void printArray(int[] arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nElements of array is: \n");
            foreach (int i in arr)
            {
                Console.Write("\t{0}", i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

        static void delimit(string arr2)
        {
            char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',', '-', ' ' };
            string[] integersList = arr2.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string value in integersList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }       

        }

        static void intConvertedList(string[] arr3)
        {

            int[] intConvertedList = new int[arr3.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < intConvertedList.Length; i++)
            {
                intConvertedList[i] = int.Parse(arr3[i]);
            }
        }

        static void sumOfNumbers(int[] arr4)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (int number in arr4)
            {
                sum += number;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + String.Join(" + ", arr4) + $" = {sum}");
            return;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write(@"Enter list of integers seperated by comma (,) or hyphen (-): ");
            string numbers = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            delimit(numbers);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need you functions to `return` their results so that you can pass those results to the next function

Comment: With Linq this is just one line `var sum = nums.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).Sum();`

Comment: Of course, @juharr is absolutely right, and that's how I'd do it, but I think there is value, especially if you are just starting out, to break down program flow into chunks in the way you have to better understand the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intConvertedList method is not returning anything.

In that function, create a new array of int, and build it up from the inputted array of string. Finally, return array of int for further processing

As follows:

```
static int[] intConvertedList(string[] arr3)
    {

        int[] intConvertedList = new int[arr3.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < intConvertedList.Length; i++)
        {
            intConvertedList[i] = int.Parse(arr3[i]);
        }
        return intConvertedList;
    }
```

In fact, none of your methods are returning anything. You should think about your methods as inputs and outputs, and think about what you want to put into them, and what you want to get out of them. You then need to "return" the thing you want out of them.

Comment: Well, none of the functions return results, so technically you're right. I would broaden your answer to encompass all of them...

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a lot of this using String's `Join` and LINQ's `Sum`.

```
var numStr = "5, 6, 7, 8";
var numbers = numStr.Split(new char[] { ',', '-', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var numbersAddStr = String.Join(" + ", numbers);

Console.WriteLine($"Output: {numbersAddStr} = {numbers.Sum(v => Convert.ToDouble(v))}");
```

Or can also use `Aggregate`.

```
var numbersAddStr = numbers.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (builder, element) => builder.Append(" + ").Append($"{element}"),
    builder => builder.Remove(0,3) // removes the leading " + "
        .ToString());
```

Comment: While technically correct, this looks a lot like homework help, so the 'long division' way of how this works is probably more beneficial for the OP's _intent_.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
        string sNumbers = "1,2,3,4,5";
        int sum = 0;           
        int[] array = sNumbers.Split(',').Select(str => int.Parse(str)).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
            sum = sum + array[i];
        }
        string sumString = string.Join(" + ", array) + " = ";
        Console.WriteLine(sumString + sum);
        Console.ReadKey();           
    }
```

This outputs what you are asking for.

Hope it helps.